# Expand array Column of PySpark DataFrame

Tags: python, dataframe, pyspark, graphframes

I am having of transferring a DataFrame into a GraphFrame using the data below. Let's consider a column of Authors in a dataframe containing an array of Strings like the one below:

```
+-----------+------------------------------------+
|ArticlePMID|               Authors              |
+-----------+------------------------------------+
|    PMID1  |['Author 1', 'Author 2', 'Author 3']|
|    PMID2  |['Author 4', 'Author 5']            |
+-----------+------------------------------------+
```

In the data table, we have a list of authors who collaborated together on the same paper. Now I want to expand the second column into a new dataframe containing the following structure:

```
+---------------+---------------+ 
| Collaborator1 | Collaborator2 |
+---------------+---------------+ 
| 'Author 1'    | 'Author 2'    |
| 'Author 1'    | 'Author 3'    |
| 'Author 2'    | 'Author 3'    |
| 'Author 4'    | 'Author 5'    |
+---------------+---------------+
```

I tried to use the explode function, but that only expands the array into a single column of authors and I lose the collaboration network.

Can some please tell me how to go around this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As long as you're using pyspark version 2.1 or above, you can use [`posexplode`](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.functions.posexplode) followed by a `join`:

First explode with the position in the array:

```python
from pyspark.sql.functions import posexplode
exploded = df.select("*", posexplode("Authors").alias("pos", "Author"))
exploded.show()
#+-----------+--------------------+---+--------+
#|ArticlePMID|             Authors|pos|  Author|
#+-----------+--------------------+---+--------+
#|      PMID1|[Author 1, Author...|  0|Author 1|
#|      PMID1|[Author 1, Author...|  1|Author 2|
#|      PMID1|[Author 1, Author...|  2|Author 3|
#|      PMID2|[Author 4, Author 5]|  0|Author 4|
#|      PMID2|[Author 4, Author 5]|  1|Author 5|
#+-----------+--------------------+---+--------+
```

Now join the exploded DataFrame to itself on the `ArticlePMID` column and select only the columns where the left side table's `pos` is less than the right side table's.

```python
exploded.alias("l").join(exploded.alias("r"), on="ArticlePMID", how="inner")\
    .where("l.pos < r.pos")\
    .selectExpr("l.Author AS Collaborator1", "r.Author AS Collaborator2")\
    .show()
#+-------------+-------------+
#|Collaborator1|Collaborator2|
#+-------------+-------------+
#|     Author 1|     Author 2|
#|     Author 1|     Author 3|
#|     Author 2|     Author 3|
#|     Author 4|     Author 5|
#+-------------+-------------+
```

Using the `pos` to filter is to avoid having the same pair of Authors listed both ways.